# How can I create my own distro and include a custom kernel & packages?

Tags: linux, kernel, packaging, lfs

I wanted to know how to add packages to the Linux kernel and then package it to a ISO or CD for friends. Thanks in advance and please don't point me to [LFS - Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/)!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you researched? What distro would you like to structure this around?

Comment: Why would you not like us to point you to LFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the distros can be used as a base and then customizations can be applied to this base, and written to an ISO.

#### Fedora

Fedora offers what's called a a "spin" or "respin". You can check them out here on the spins website:

- http://spins.fedoraproject.org/

It's pretty straight-forward to "roll your own" versions of Fedora, mixing in your own custom RPMs as well as customizing the UI.

You can even use the tool `revisor` which is a GUI for selecting the packages you want to bundle into your own custom .ISO. There's a pretty good tutorial here, titled: [Create Your Own Fedora Distribution with Revisor](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Create_Your_Own_Fedora_Distribution_with_Revisor).

The primary page for `revisor` is here:

- http://revisor.fedoraunity.org/

*screenshot of revisor*
   [image: ss of revisor]

#### Ubuntu

Ubuntu offers this howto on the community wiki, titled: [LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch).

For Ubuntu/Debian you also have a couple of other alternatives.

- [remastersys](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWk7FCevYBU)
- [relink](http://mijyn.github.io/relinux/)

Of these 2, `relink` seems to be the most promising in both ease of use and being able to create a fairly customized version of Ubuntu.

#### References

- [Relinux – An easy way to create a Linux distro](http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/relinux-a-way-to-create-a-bootable-iso-out-of-your-system/)
- [relink launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/relinux)

Comment: Thanks but how would I do this all from scratch and add packages to my ISO/CD with my custom kernel? Thanks

Comment: @user2589636 - it all depends on which option you go with. For either you'll have to compile you're own version of the kernel and bundle it into a .deb or .rpm file. For your custom packages, you'd have to roll these into .deb or .rpm files as well and put them into the RPMS directory as part of the .ISO file.

Comment: I am totally lost... Can you just please point me to a article on how to make a custom kernel. I just created one with the 'make xconfig' command... And i am now totally lost.. Thank you...

Comment: @user2589636 - which distro did you want to use? I just updated my question to include a GUI called `revisor` that you can use to create custom Fedora ISOs.

Comment: Yes i know i guess i just want a debian like system with apt-get i know you can probably get apt-get on rpm based distros but i heard fedora is a resource hunger OS. And even if i do create my custom ISO/CD with revisor then how will i give my users the source code, it is stated in the GPL and how will i supply that? Thank you.

Comment: Here's a tutorial that shows how to use the tool `remastersys` for making a Ubuntu custom distro: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWk7FCevYBU

Comment: Thanks slm i have also tried remastersys, but it has a few errors and problems i always wanted to do it from scratch.

Comment: @user2589636 - there is also [relink](https://launchpad.net/relinux) for Ubuntu. There's a tutorial for it here, titled: [Relinux – An easy way to create a Linux distro](http://lkubuntu.wordpress.com/2011/10/10/relinux-a-way-to-create-a-bootable-iso-out-of-your-system/).

Comment: Thanks i will try it out, Thank you for all the help and i will try it out. And if i have a problem i will report back to you. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2589636 - good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/).

Arch Linux allows you to build your system from the first floor up. You start with nearly nothing and install packages to your desire.

Take a look at the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/) for installation instructions. Arch makes it easy to create [custom installation media](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Remastering_the_Install_ISO).

Answer (score 0):

One doesn't "add packages to the Linux kernel". Instead what one does is [create a custom distro](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+custom+distro) and then distribute that.

Comment: How would make a custom distro then? I have the custom kernel, but how do I add packages to my ISO/CD. Thanks!